# Nginx + Docker containers

Tags: nginx

I am trying to user nginx as a reverse proxy for multiple docker containers

I have stuff like redmine, jenkins, owncloud etc and a domain `example.com`

What I would like to do is be able to access these containers in the following manner:

- example.com/redmine
- example.com/jenkins
- example.com/owncloud

The problem (I think) is my nginx.conf file, but I have only modest experience with nginx

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
#       listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com

      location / {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html index.htm;
      }

      location /redmine {
          proxy_pass         http://redmine_app:3000/;
          proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      }

      error_page 500 502 503 503 /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      }
    }
}
```

The `index.html` page at the root, `/`, works fine

```
      location / {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html index.htm;
      }
```

but if I modify it to `/test`

```
      location /test {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index index.html index.htm;
      }
```

it does not.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you mean by now working?

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan I don't understand your question

Comment: What's the error you get? 404 Not Found? What's not working exactly?